# Unable to ReadXML with SchemaId

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @XML XML
SET @XML =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dealer schemaID="DL" xmlns="http://www.abc.zy/kudos/kentucy" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abc.zy/kudos/kentucy/ik schema13_dealer(dl).xsd">
   <Head>
      <ImporterNr>ZZ840</ImporterNr>
      <ForwarderNr>XYZA</ForwarderNr>
      <RecordType>MR</RecordType>
      <Filename>FZ12325</Filename>
      <Items>
         <Item>
            <AddressType>L</AddressType>
            <DealerNr>KZ DEALER LLC</DealerNr>
            <ShortName>KZ D </ShortName>
            <DealerName>DEALER T </DealerName>
            <Street>Riverpol Romerro Calle 31D No. 12-25</Street>
            <Country>SG </Country>
            <ZIP>1234</ZIP>
            <Town>MCGY</Town>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Head>
   </Dealer>'
```

My Query Goes like this

```
SELECT
   Cust.value('(ImporterNr)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS 'ImporterNr',
   Cust.value('(ForwarderNr)[1]', 'nVarchar(50)') AS 'ForwarderNr',
    Cust.value('(Items/Item/AddressType)[1]', 'nVarchar(50)') AS 'AddressType'
FROM
   @XML.nodes('/Dealer/Head') AS AOC(Cust)
```

The 3 columns ImporterNr,ForwarderNr,AddressType returns NULL Values Am I doing anything wrong your suggestions please.

Declare @XML XML
SET @XML =

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dealer schemaID="DL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abc.zy/kudos/kentucy/ik schema13_dealer(dl).xsd">
   <Head>
      <ImporterNr>ZZ840</ImporterNr>
      <ForwarderNr>XYZA</ForwarderNr>
      <RecordType>MR</RecordType>
      <Filename>FZ12325</Filename>
      <Items>
         <Item>
            <AddressType>L</AddressType>
            <DealerNr>KZ DEALER LLC</DealerNr>
            <ShortName>KZ D </ShortName>
            <DealerName>DEALER T </DealerName>
            <Street>Riverpol Romerro Calle 31D No. 12-25</Street>
            <Country>SG </Country>
            <ZIP>1234</ZIP>
            <Town>MCGY</Town>
         </Item>
         <Item>
            <AddressType>L</AddressType>
            <DealerNr>ALIAV</DealerNr>
            <ShortName>K V </ShortName>
            <DealerName>K T VALLEDUPAR                              </DealerName>
            <Street>CARRERA 19 KM 0-700 CLUB DEPORTIVO RUDATO         </Street>
            <Country>ZO </Country>
            <ZIP>123       </ZIP>
            <Town>VALLEDUPAR                                        </Town>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Head>
   </Dealer>'
```

What If Multiple Nodes are present the Query doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Add namespace to your query:

```
Declare @XML XML
SET @XML =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dealer schemaID="DL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abc.zy/kudos/kentucy/ik schema13_dealer(dl).xsd">
   <Head>
      <ImporterNr>ZZ840</ImporterNr>
      <ForwarderNr>XYZA</ForwarderNr>
      <RecordType>MR</RecordType>
      <Filename>FZ12325</Filename>
      <Items>
         <Item>
            <AddressType>L</AddressType>
            <DealerNr>KZ DEALER LLC</DealerNr>
            <ShortName>KZ D </ShortName>
            <DealerName>DEALER T </DealerName>
            <Street>Riverpol Romerro Calle 31D No. 12-25</Street>
            <Country>SG </Country>
            <ZIP>1234</ZIP>
            <Town>MCGY</Town>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Head>
   </Dealer>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.abc.zy/kudos/kentucy' as ns1)
SELECT
   Cust.value('(ns1:ImporterNr)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS 'ImporterNr',
   Cust.value('(ns1:ForwarderNr)[1]', 'nVarchar(50)') AS 'ForwarderNr',
   Cust.value('(ns1:Items/ns1:Item/ns1:AddressType)[1]', 'nVarchar(50)') AS 'AddressType'
FROM
   @XML.nodes('/ns1:Dealer/ns1:Head') AS AOC(Cust)
```

Or remove it from XML.

Comment: It Worked Thank you very much.

Comment: I just want to know what if multiple nodes are present. ie <items><item><AddressType></AddressType></item></items>

Comment: @explore365 update your question please, or create a new one